# Wait 60 seconds then resend if Send-MailMessage failed Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, error-handling, try-catch, powershell-2.0

I have a script that sends an email if a task fails (SendMailErr). I would like to add in retrying to send the email if the previous send-mailmessage failed. I had tried to put it into a try catch finally loop within the function but it didn't work as expected. Here is my code

```
$waitMail = 60
$sendErr = "Error Sending Email to SI Team: $_. Retrying in $waitMail minute(s)"

function SendMailErr { 
$MessageParameters = @{
    From = $from
    To = $to
    Subject = "ALERT: Backup Failed for $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
    Body = $body | Out-String 
    SmtpServer = $Smtp
    Priority = "High"
    Attachments = $attachments
}
try {   Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters -EA Stop
        Exit
    }
catch { Write-Log $sendErr
        Sleep $waitMail
        Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters
        Exit
      }
finaly {  
        Write-Log "Error: Unable to send email to SI Team"
        Exit
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure there's a better way to structure it, my googling just hasn't found it yet.

Thanks,
Amelia

---

I've figured this out in my own clumsy way...

Thank you to the person that pointed out I had an Exit within the trap.

The following works for me now

```
function SendMailErr { 
$MessageParameters = @{
    From = $from
    To = $to
Subject = "ALERT: Backup Failed for $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
SmtpServer = $smtp
    Body = $body
Priority = "High"

}
try {
    Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters  -EA Stop;

    }
catch { Write-Host $sendErr
    Sleep $waitMail
    Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters
      }

Exit
}
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What did you expect? What happened?

Comment: Sorry. It didn't send an email at all. I had hoped that it would try and send the email and if it failed to write in the log file that if failed but was trying again. I had found that send-mailmessage occassionally didn't send but retrying manually a minute later it worked (SMTP service not available)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just to let you know, you can answer your own question here, it's perfectly ok.

Comment: Can you move the solution down to an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SendMailErr { 
$MessageParameters = @{
From = $from
To = $to
Subject = "ALERT: Backup Failed for $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN - $((Get-        Date).ToShortDateString())"
SmtpServer = $smtp
Body = $body
Priority = "High"

}
try {
Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters  -EA Stop;

}
catch { Write-Host $sendErr
Sleep $waitMail
Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters
  }

Exit
}
```